# Why fancybox doesn't bind at the first time on this code?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have an input element and a link next to it. User enters some text in input and click link to do a query to find something related to what he enters. The result should be shown using fancybox. Here is my js code:

```
$(".srcaut").click(function() { 
        if($(this).prev("input").val() == '') {
            alert('Empty field');
            return false;
        }

        srch = $(this).attr("id").replace("srch-",'');

        $(this).attr('href',Url+'/'+srch+'/'+$(this).prev("input").val());
        $(this).fancybox();

    }).prev("input").keypress(function(even) {
         if(even.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).next('.srcaut').click();
            return false;
        }

});
```

But fancybox isn't shown the first time user enter some text and click on link or hit the 'Enter' key after the page loaded. but after that is works.

What is the problem. Is seems fancybox doesn't bind to link at the first time, but why ?

Comment: is your click function getting called on the first time ?

Comment: it is called when user click link or hit 'Enter' key.

Comment: Anything in the console? What do you get when doing this: `console.log(Url+'/'+srch+'/'+$(this).prev("input").val());`

Comment: url is shown ok in consol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `.fancybox()` on a link will not *show* the fancy box, it will just *prepare* the link to display a fancy box when it is clicked. That's the reason why it only works the second time as the fancy box is prepared inside the `click` handler.

You'll probably have to call `.fancybox()` on your links when the document is loaded, but this raises the question of having it work with a link that is dynamically constructed based on the `input`'s content. You might want to try and construct the link on the `blur` event of your `input`.

> How can I prevent to display it in a if condition inside the click
>   event of link?

Before calling `.fancybox()`, you can register a `click` handler that will [stop event propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) if the `input` is empty, see example at http://jsbin.com/exomad/3

Comment: thank you ybo, it works ok when I bind in on link when the page is loaded. but the problem is when the input is empty and user click link.At that time I don't want to show fancybox but by binding on document load time it is shown, so I think to put it on click event.

Comment: How can I prevent to display it in a if condition inside the click event of link?

Comment: Added the answer to your second question

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this for other who face the similar issue..

in my case i had

```
$('#addvideos').on("click",function(){
    $(".modal").fancybox(fancybox_default);
});
```

fancybox_default <-- stores the fancy box configuration {height,width}

## addvideos <-- point to a url element

so in my case the configurations wont load up for the first time when i click the url but works after that. (i mean it works (it shows the popup) but it wont load the height and width for the popup)

i had to add var trash = $(".modal").fancybox(fancybox_default); <-- before the on click handler... // just load that thing onece and keep it in a  variable...

and it worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by initialising fancybox before binding click event for dynamically generated anchor tag (i suppose it could work even if you init before calling)

```
 $('#a_email' + resultId).fancybox({
                    //jq('#a_email' + resultId).fancybox({               
                    'width': '45%',
                    'height': '55%',
                    'autoScale': true,
                    'scrolling': 'no',
                    'transitionIn': 'fade',
                    'transitionOut': 'fade',
                    'type': 'iframe'
                });
```

And then calling fancybox directly

```
$.fancybox({                        
                        'width': '45%',
                        'height': '55%',
                        'autoScale': true,
                        'scrolling': 'no',
                        'transitionIn': 'fade',
                        'transitionOut': 'fade',
                        'type': 'iframe',
                        'href': url
                    });
```

Any thoughts?